# SUM and JOIN clause in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

There are 3 tables with respective columns :
wc_dept   : dept_id,dept_name
wc_doctor : dept_id,doc_id,doc_name,consult_fee
wc_patient: doc_id,consult_id,patient_name

For the following queries I am getting different results :

Query 1 :

```
select dept_name,sum(consult_fee)
from wc_doctor do,wc_dept dp,wc_patient p
where
do.dept_cd=dp.dept_cd
AND
do.doc_id=p.doc_id
group by dept_name;
```

The output for the above query is a very large amount of money for every department compared to the actual amount i.e, sum of consultation fee in each department.

Query 2 :

```
select dept_name,sum(consult_fee)
from wc_doctor do,wc_dept dp
where
do.dept_cd=dp.dept_cd
group by dept_name;
```

The output of the Query 2 gives the exact sum of consultation fee for each department.

**Why is the difference between query1 and query2 ? how is consult_id column behaving in query1?**

Comment: Learn how to use explicit `join` syntax.  That will help you keep track of your join conditions.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: Did you try removing the sum and group bys from each query and seeing the difference in the rows returned? You're joining an additional table in the first query, so I would expect to see many more rows in the first query, hence a bigger sum.

Comment: Given that you haven't probided any sample data, that's the only conclusion I can see. I'm guessing that a given doctor sees multiple patients! What is the actual requirement you're trying to solve? I would say that the first query has more actual meaning than the second - I mean, why do you need to know the sum of each doctor's consult fee per dept? Surely it would make more sense to know how much each dept made for seeing patients?

Comment: To all those who are down voting its highly encouraging of you for a beginner like me. I am learning SQL by myself and I can't afford an instructor so after few hours of trying this and that when something doesn't makes sense or I need a better understanding I ask a question here, which I can see I'll soon be deprived of.

Comment: I didnt down vote but I guess some people get demaning regarding how the question is written. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some suggestion.  So when you fail to provide some data sample this may be consider an incomplete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that the join happens before aggregation, and that joins will duplicate values in the parent table for each row in the joined child table.

`consult_fee` is a column in `wc_doctor`.  You want to sum that once per row in `wc_doctor`.  When you join to `wc_patient, the`consult_fee` for each doctor is repeated, *per patient*, and the sum will add up over all that duplication.

If you really want to include the doctor's consult fee in a query that includes patients, you need to aggregate it separately in a subquery, *then* join that result against patients.

Answer (score 2):

Well query1 and query2 are different.

- In Second Query  you are `SUM` how much charge each doctor in the department for check a single patient.
- But in the first one you are `SUM` how much all the patient are pay to the department

Comment: Maybe you would like watch some [**tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB) I learm asp and mvc from him and I like more listen and watching than just reading. `JOIN` is video #12